# How can I calculate values within pauses in an XML file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file with the following information:

```
<Key Time="54288" Type="insert" Value="E" />
<Key Time="55288" Type="insert" Value="A" />
<Key Time="58298" Type="insert" Value="H" />
<Key Time="58398" Type="insert" Value="A" />
<Key Time="58498" Type="insert" Value="L" />
<Key Time="59298" Type="insert" Value="L" />    
<Key Time="64298" Type="insert" Value="O" />
```

I first need to calculate the total pause duration between each `Key` entry, but only when the pauses (the intervals since the previous `Time`) are equal to or higher than 2400.

For that I got the script below, which also shows when the pause starts.

```
perl -nle '
   /<Key +Time\s*=\s*"([0-9]+)\s*"/ and push @nums,$1; 
   END{ 
       for(1..$#nums){ 
           $pause=$nums[$_]-$nums[$_-1];
           $pause >=2400 ? print "$pause started at ".$nums[$_-1] : ()
       }
   }' your_file_here > output_file
```

This outputs

```
3010 started at 55288
5000 started at 59298
```

However, now I need to improve the script to retrieve all values in between two >= 2400-long pauses, also including the value where the pause starts. For instance, from `Time="54288"` to `Time="55288"` I have `EA`; from `Time="58298"` to `Time="59298"` I have `HALL` etc.

Comment: I don't get it. Your existing script will find the pauses from A to H and another from L to O, correct? So, if your new script should find letters from start of pause inclusive to end of pause non-inclusive, you should get AHAL, surely?

Comment: By the way, just for the sake of understanding your question, and ease of checking answers, it might be better to edit the question  and use unique letters!

Comment: @Mark: What I *think* is wanted is a list of `value` attributes *separated* by intervals >= 2400, so `EA`, `HALL`, `O`. At least that's what my answer does! If so then there was a typo in the final value of the range creating `HALL`, which should be `59298` instead of `64298`. I've fixed the question, hoping I'm right.

Comment: @ials: Anything longer than a few short statements should be put into a file as a program. Long command-line programs don't work well, especially for debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I *think* you may want, which is to produce lists of the `Value` attributes separated by pauses greater than 40 minutes.

I've used a proper XML parser module [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML%3a%3aTwig) to do it. Using regular expressions to parse XML is asking for trouble.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my @nums;
my $start_time;
my @blocks = ( '' );

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
   twig_handlers => { Key => \&key_handler }
);
$twig->parse(*DATA);

print "$_\n" for @blocks;

sub key_handler {
  my ($twig, $key) = @_;
  my $time = $key->{att}{Time};

  if (defined $start_time) {
    my $pause = $time - $start_time; 
    push @blocks, ("$pause from $start_time to $time", '') if $pause >= 2400;
  }

  $start_time = $time;
  $blocks[-1] .= $key->{att}{Value};
}

__DATA__
<root>
  <Key Time="54288" Type="insert" Value="E" />
  <Key Time="55288" Type="insert" Value="A" />
  <Key Time="58298" Type="insert" Value="H" />
  <Key Time="58398" Type="insert" Value="A" />
  <Key Time="58498" Type="insert" Value="L" />
  <Key Time="59298" Type="insert" Value="L" />    
  <Key Time="64298" Type="insert" Value="O" />
</root>
```

**output**

```
EA
3010 from 55288 to 58298
HALL
5000 from 59298 to 64298
O
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, @Borodin. Many thanks. I made a single change to get the data from an XML file instead of including it in the script file [$twig->parsefile( 'myFile.xml');]. However, I was wondering how I could manage to process a batch of XML files simultaneously and get a single file with the results provided according to their original files?

Comment: @ials: That is a different question and should be posed as such. Do you know so little programming that you can't embed that algorithm inside a `for (@ARGV) { ... }`?

Comment: I am newbie, @Borodin... Programming is actually not my working area, but I need at times... I'll try your hint at (@ARGV). Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A solution modeling Borodin's, but using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod) instead:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

my $string = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $string);

my @blocks = '';

my $lasttime;
for my $node ($dom->findnodes('//Key')) {
    my $time = $node->getAttribute('Time');

    if (defined $lasttime) {
        my $pause = $time - $lasttime;
        push @blocks, "pause from $lasttime to $time", '' if $pause >= 2400;
    }
    $blocks[-1] .= $node->getAttribute('Value');
    $lasttime = $time;
}

print "$_\n" for @blocks;

__DATA__
<root>
  <Key Time="54288" Type="insert" Value="E" />
  <Key Time="55288" Type="insert" Value="A" />
  <Key Time="58298" Type="insert" Value="H" />
  <Key Time="58398" Type="insert" Value="A" />
  <Key Time="58498" Type="insert" Value="L" />
  <Key Time="59298" Type="insert" Value="L" />    
  <Key Time="64298" Type="insert" Value="O" />
</root>
```